# Processing large number of big Http requests using REST and java

Tags: java, rest, web-services, http

I have to design a JAVA REST API which accepts Json requests and the data needs to be uploaded to Database. The data contains images too(Base64 encoded ) and so the size of each request is around 25MBs. The problem starts when frequency of these requests increases (I have tested it for 10 req in 1 second) and at this rate the API throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` or `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.
I tried to increase heap size but it didn't help. 
While trying to solve the problem I tried to disable any processing and just read the request on server. And I got the same exception even without any processing on request.

Here is what I do when I receive a request

1) Read from request and store everything in a string

2) Get json object from this string (I am using org.json)

3) Rest of the processing (which I skipped for testing and still I am getting that exception).

My question is how to handle this much data? Should I save each request in a file and process fixed number of request at a time(which I think should be avoided ) ? Should I use a different library or algorithm? Any suggestions will help.

I am using Jboss-eap-6.4

Comment: With such high volume of data an auto scaling solution will be needed sooner or later. Would using jboss in a cluster mode be an option? On [HTTP CLUSTERING AND LOAD BALANCING](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/chap-http_clustering_and_load_balancing) there are details about how clustering could be configured with jboss-eap-6.4

Comment: @ValentinCarnu No, I cant use clustering.. Is there any other way to process these request.. It is not necessary that every request is to be processed simlutaneously. I can keep them in quese. Is there any way to configure maximim number of concurent requests in JBOSS? I googled it but I am not getting anything. Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with JBOSS configuration, though it seems it is possible to limit the maximum number of requests by setting `max-connections` attribute for the used connector (check section [15.3. Servlet/HTTP Configuration](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html-single/administration_and_configuration_guide/#ServletHTTP_Configuration))